# How to delete row from postgresql table without cascade

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume my application two different tables, one of which references the other. And also an on delete cascade is defined?

I do not want to delete on delete cascade constraint but, sometimes from my local I want to delete that ignores cascade statement such as:

```
delete_without_cascade from table1 where id = id1
```

Is there a way to do that

Comment: So are you saying you want orphaned child records when you delete from parent or that you want to know how to delete the child records first easily? I'm not sure what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Cascade on delete will **delete children records when the parent is deleted**. If you do not want to do that then you have to do something with the values in the column bound by the FK constraint because the db schema should not allow a record to have an orphaned value. If the column allows for `null` values then execute an update before to set the the FK column value to `null` before running the delete.

If the cascade was not present you would normally get an error when executing the `delete` statement because there would be orphaned records in other tables.

In case you are not understanding how Cascade on delete works, it does not work in reverse, ie. deleting a record that references a parent table will not cause the parent record to be deleted.

Comment: Actuallt I wanted my application to delete child nodes, but when i use pgadmin for some modifications, i want to see the error about the child record. Anyway, as far as i understood there is no way build such a query. Thank you for your answer.